# Dice rolling outputs

Tags: python, dice

I have finished this code but I need help understanding why the outputs aren't the same as desired. Here is my code. Also my professor said to use a seed of 237.

```
import random
rng = random.Random()
rng.seed(237)

NumberOfRolls = int(input("How many dice?:"))
NumberOfFaces = int(input("How many sides of each dice?:"))
numberOfTrials = int(input('How many trials? Enter:'))

# Set the number of elements in the list
#def throwDice():
def throwDice(NumberOfRolls):
    return random.randrange(1,NumberOfFaces)

def rollAllDice(NumberOfRolls):
  sum = 0;
  for i in range(NumberOfRolls):
    v = throwDice(NumberOfRolls);
    sum = sum + v;
    # print(v);
  return sum;



# perform simulation, record and print frequencies
index = (NumberOfRolls*NumberOfFaces)+1;
frequency = [0]*index
rel_frequency_list = [0]*index
exp_prob_list =[0]*index

for i in range(numberOfTrials):
  ind = rollAllDice(NumberOfRolls);
  frequency[ind] = frequency[ind]+1;
# end for
print()
#print("Frequencies:")



# calculate relative frequencies, probabilities and errors
relativeFrequency = [0, 0]
probability = [0,0]
error = [0,0]
for i in range(2, len(frequency)):
  rel_frequency_list[i] = frequency[i]/numberOfTrials;
  exp_prob_list[i] = frequency[i]/100;


#print(relativeFrequency)
#print(probability)
#print(error)
print()


# print results
f1 = "{0:<10}{1:<22}{2:<22}{3:<22}"
f2 = 71*"-"
f3 = "{0:>3}       {1:<22.15f}{2:<22.15f}{3:<.15f}"
print(f1.format("Sum","Frequency","Relative Frequency","Experimental Probability"))
print(f2)
for i in range(NumberOfRolls, len(frequency)):
   print(f3.format(i, frequency[i], rel_frequency_list[i], exp_prob_list[i]),"%")
#end for
```

This is my output for 3 dice , 6 sides, 10,000 trials

```
Sum       Frequency             Relative Frequency    Experimental Probability

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  3       75.000000000000000    0.007500000000000     0.750000000000000 %
  4       232.000000000000000   0.023200000000000     2.320000000000000 %
  5       454.000000000000000   0.045400000000000     4.540000000000000 %
  6       831.000000000000000   0.083100000000000     8.310000000000000 %
  7       1214.000000000000000  0.121400000000000     12.140000000000001 %
  8       1468.000000000000000  0.146800000000000     14.680000000000000 %
  9       1491.000000000000000  0.149100000000000     14.910000000000000 %
 10       1445.000000000000000  0.144500000000000     14.449999999999999 %
 11       1157.000000000000000  0.115700000000000     11.570000000000000 %
 12       828.000000000000000   0.082800000000000     8.279999999999999 %
 13       476.000000000000000   0.047600000000000     4.760000000000000 %
 14       230.000000000000000   0.023000000000000     2.300000000000000 %
 15       99.000000000000000    0.009900000000000     0.990000000000000 %
 16       0.000000000000000     0.000000000000000     0.000000000000000 %
 17       0.000000000000000     0.000000000000000     0.000000000000000 %
 18       0.000000000000000     0.000000000000000     0.000000000000000 %
```

This is the desired (same outputs):

```
Sum Frequency Relative Frequency Experimental Probability
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 45 0.00450 0.45 %
 4 126 0.01260 1.26 %
 5 281 0.02810 2.81 %
 6 494 0.04940 4.94 %
 7 677 0.06770 6.77 %
 8 968 0.09680 9.68 %
 9 1191 0.11910 11.91 %
 10 1257 0.12570 12.57 %
 11 1257 0.12570 12.57 %
 12 1164 0.11640 11.64 %
 13 932 0.09320 9.32 %
 14 683 0.06830 6.83 %
 15 469 0.04690 4.69 %
 16 282 0.02820 2.82 %
 17 122 0.01220 1.22 %
 18 52 0.00520 0.52 %
```

Comment: The upper bound of `random.randrange()` is exclusive. Try using `NumberOfFaces + 1`.

Comment: or try `random.randint()` it's simpler :)

Comment: Your seed is also not doing what you think it is.  Use `random.seed(237)` and then `random.randrange()` or `randint()`.  Right now you're setting the seed of a new rng and never using it.

Comment: Using randint yield closer and better results.
How can I use the seed?

Comment: `random.seed(237)`  When you call random.randint() it uses the internal rng.  You created a new one, but never used it - rng.randint() would use it.

Comment: oh wow I totally forgot to use that. I had it initially but removed it on accident. Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: If anyone see's this, how can i remove the extra 0's that show. For example, the frequency is 47.00000000

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reorganized version:

```
from random import Random

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

class Dice:
    def __init__(self, num_dice, num_faces, seed=None):
        self.num_dice = num_dice
        self.num_faces = num_faces
        self.rng = Random()
        if seed is not None:
            self.rng.seed(seed)

    def roll(self):
        return sum(self.rng.randint(1, self.num_faces) for _ in range(self.num_dice))

    def histogram(self, num_trials):
        hist = [0] * (self.num_dice * self.num_faces + 1)
        for _ in range(num_trials):
            hist[self.roll()] += 1
        return hist

def main():
    num_dice = get_int("How many dice? ")
    num_faces = get_int("How many sides on each die? ")
    num_trials = get_int("How many trials? ")

    dice = Dice(num_dice, num_faces, 237)
    hist = dice.histogram(num_trials)

    print("Sum Frequency Relative Frequency Experimental Probability")
    print("-" * 70)

    lo = num_dice
    hi = num_dice * num_faces
    for n in range(lo, hi + 1):
        freq = hist[n]
        rfreq = freq / num_trials
        print("{:d} {:d} {:0.5f} {:0.2f} %".format(n, freq, rfreq, 100. * rfreq))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure OOP is a great fit for this, and your model doesn't make sense to me. a `Dice` object probably shouldn't have an attribute indicating how many dice it is. Maybe `class DiceGame`?

Comment: @AdamSmith OOP is not *necessary* here; it could easily be done with plain functions. On the other hand, OOP makes it easy to compartmentalize the logic, making it easier to think about each piece of the problem, and reduces the dependence on shared variables, ie roll() needs to know how many dice with how many faces, but you don't want to keep re-specifying every time you call it.

Comment: This is probably Johnny-Come-Lately syndrome for me. Been spending a bunch of time in Haskell-land lately, so suddenly OOP looks like too much overhead. When all you have is a hammer, all the world should be functions -- or something like that :D

Comment: @AdamSmith for naming, `Dice` as in `a set of dice` seemed idiomatic to me; if you preferred, you could of course call it `DiceCup`. `DiceGame` isn't quite right, because it doesn't have any game logic. `histogram`, strictly, should probably be a stand-alone function rather than a member of `Dice`.

Comment: Thanks! 

Also can anyone help me remove the extra 0's? For example the whole numbers include .00000000 after.

Comment: @YearofTheBoar you get the trailing zeros because you format it as `{1:<22.15f}` (the `f` means `float`). Try `d` instead (for integer). Why does d mean integer? Uh... no idea, but it does.

Comment: (d -> digit, i -> imaginary)

Comment: @HughBothwell I change that and it gives me : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python projects\dice.py", line 93, in <module>
    print(f3.format(i, frequency[i], rel_frequency_list[i], exp_prob_list[i]),"%")
ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier

Comment: @YearofTheBoar go look up string formatting specifications in Python. It'll solve this problem for you.